# Symfony2, Set username then on create user

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have login / register form.

I'm not using username, except this using email on login. Also have implement **UserInterface**.

1) Should I set email in username entity field ?

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
* @Assert\Email()
*/
private $username;
```

2) Maybe should use auto generated username ? e.g. firstname_lastname.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());

    $user->setPassword($password);

    //Maybe setUsername should be in other place ?
    $user->setUsername($user->getName().'_'.$user->getLastName());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Set email. Name and surname combination will be not unique.

Comment: Or you can just not have a username property at all and just have getUsername() return the email.

Comment: I'm using $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(); it not will be a problem ?

Comment: The only requirement is that the `getUsername()` method of your `UserInterface` implementation returns a unique result. It doesn't matter if that's really a username or just an e-mail address that is unique per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method in your User.php entity class. It will set email in username field.

```
/**
 * Set username to email.
 *
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function setUsernameToEmail()
{
    $this->username          = $this->email;
    $this->usernameCanonical = $this->emailCanonical;
}
```